# Why thread blocked by synchronized can't be interrupted?

Tags: java

In the java.lang.Thread, we see that the thread enters BLOCKED state when waiting for a monitor lock, this is different to the WAITING state when the thread calls LockSupport.park for example. 
But when I learn the monitor lock implementation of HotSpot JVM in ObjectMonitor.cpp, I saw that it uses "park" when waiting for the monitor lock holding by other thread. I think it is same park function as the implementation of LockSupport.park.
So my questions are:

1. Why the park for monitor lock makes the thread enters BLOCKED state but the park for LockSupport.park makes the thread enters WAITING state?
2. Why the park for monitor lock can't be interrupted(It's said by Doug Lea in "Concurrent Programming in Java", "There is no way to back off from an attempt to acquire a lock if it is already held, to give up 
   after waiting for a specified time, or to cancel a lock attempt after an interrupt. This can make it difficult to recover from liveness problems.") but the park for LockSupport.park can be interrupted?

Comment: Because synchronization was designed in the early 90s, whereas Locks were designed later to overcome the limitations of synchronization.

Comment: If you want interruptible locking you can use [`ReentrantLock::lockInterruptibly`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) instead of instristic locks.

Comment: yes,I know the difference between synchronized and Locks, just curious about why they have this difference in the level of JVM's implementation...